# Foreign Keys Contraint Formed Incorrectly

Tags: php, html, sql, web

```
 ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 2 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4; CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `reservations`(
    `reservation_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `reservation_dte` DATE NOT NULL,
    `table_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `slot_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `contact_no` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`reservation_id`),
    KEY `account_id`(`account_id`),
    KEY `table_id_idx`(`table_id`),
    KEY `slot_d_idx`(`slot_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `reservation_id` FOREIGN KEY(`account_id`) REFERENCES `accounts`(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `slot_id` FOREIGN KEY(`slot_id`) REFERENCES `time_slots`(`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `table_id` FOREIGN KEY(`table_id`) REFERENCES `table_info`(`table_id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 7 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
-- Dumping structure for table personalised_prebooking.table_info
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_info`(
    `table_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `no_ofpersons` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `available` CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'Y',
    PRIMARY KEY(`table_id`)
) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 42 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8mb4;
```

I GET

> #1005 - Can't create table `u808288638_lwatts`.`reservations` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (Details…)

Comment: Which foreign key is it having the problem? (Remove stuff not needed to reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Can you describe more your problem?

Comment: @Lewis . . . You need to define the referenced tables (the ones with the primary keys) *before* you define the foreign key constraint.